# Unable to overwrite CWM with TWRP

Tags: twrp

I'm trying to get TWRP running instead of CWM on my HTX One X. 
When flashing the recovery through fastboot, and rebooting the phone - the bootloader choice for "recovery" goes straight to CWM.

I tried flashing TWRP through GooManager, and the same thing happens. 
It kinda seems like the files doesn't get overwritten...

This all started because I wanted to swap the custom rom running (at the moment it's Cyanogen 10.2.0). But even overwriting the boot.img file seems impossible, since all other ROMs just throws the phone in to a bootloop.

The same happens when trying to update to Cyanogen 10.2.1.. (As I've seen many have to manually flash a new boot.img through fastboot)

Any thoughts on how to solve such a case?

Edit 1 ->
Commands ran in fastboot:

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot reboot
```

Started phone in bootloader and selected "Recovery" from the menu. CWM shows up and no sign of TWRP.

When trying to flash the new Roms (not cyanogen), I flashed the accompanying boot.img through fastboot.

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
```

No luck, and it get stuck on the HTC-Screen..

Comment: Have you tried flashing using Flashify?

Comment: I have not tried using Flashify no. I'll have a look at that.

Comment: Added more information as you asked for @Chahk

Comment: @xstnc Try different release of TWRP for Your device.

Answer (score 0):

I found, that in my case flashing with heimdall did the deal. In my case, the CM recovery was in the KERNEL partition, so reflashing that partition with an apropriate zImage did the trick for me. The command I used:

```
sudo heimdall flash --KERNEL zImage
```